# EF VB Many-To-Many LINQ questions and concerns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Asking for help on the following 2 questions (as unable to find direct or similar solutions online).

**The set...**

```
Partial Public Class Profile
    Public Property Id As Long
    Public Property ProfileTitle As String

    Public Overridable Property Categories As ICollection(Of Category) = New HashSet(Of Category)
End Class

Partial Public Class Category
    Public Property Id As Long
    Public Property ParentId As Long
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overridable Property ChildrenCategories As ICollection(Of Category) = New HashSet(Of Category)
    Public Overridable Property PrentCategory As Category
    Public Overridable Property Profiles As ICollection(Of Profile) = New HashSet(Of Profile)
End Class
```

**Idea** is to list all distinct categories with count of profiles in each category (limited by profiles).

Similar to the following SQL:

```
SELECT c.Id,c.Name,Count(p.Id) Cnt
FROM Categories c
    JOIN ProfilesInCategories pic ON pic.CategoryId = c.Id
    JOIN Profiles p On p.Id = pic.ProfileId
WHERE p.ProfileTitle like ('%frost%')
GROUP BY c.Id,c.Name
ORDER BY c.Name ASC
```

**The questions are:**

1. I am new to EF and to LINQ. Cannot figure out the the LINQ statement for the categories

   (From c In AppModel.Categories.Include("Profiles")
                               From p In c.Profiles
                               Where p.ProfileTitle.Contains("frost")
                           Select New With {.Id = c.Id, .Name = c.Name, .Count = c.Profiles.Count}).Distinct()

All though the above statement returns the right categories for the right profiles, it does not return the count correctly (the count that comes back is for all profiles in returned categories).

2. Would this be the most efficient way to do this? Is there a better technique considering the Profiles will be further limited by other criterias?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

---

I was able to make LINQ to return the right result, but still wondering if this is the best solution for this...

```
From c In Categories.Include("Profiles") _
        From p In c.Profiles _
        Where p.ProfileTitle.Contains("frost") _
        Group c By c.Id, c.Name Into Group _
        Select New With {.Id = Id, .Name = Name, .Count = Group.Count()}
```

Or

```
From p In Profiles.Include("Categories") _
        Where p.ProfileTitle.Contains("frost") _ 
        From c in p.Categories _
        Group c By c.Id, c.Name Into Group _
        Select New With {.Id = Id, .Name = Name, .cnt = Group.Count}
```

Comment: You need a group by in your LINQ. Something like "group c by new { c.Id, c.Name } into g" then your select would become "select new { Id = g.Key.Id, Name = g.Key.Name, Count = g.Count() }"

Comment: I have updated my question with a solution I have found up to date (with your help), however there is still an unanswered question... Is this the best and/or the right way to do this?

Comment: Well, I frequently use code similar to that. EF does some things behind the scenes, but if you want to see the actual SQL that results you can try logging https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx